# App.getPath("userData") seems to give the wrong path

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a simple app which is based off electron-quick-start with almost no changes. I'm trying to use nedb and pass it in my userData path.

My Package.json

```
  "name": "my-electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
  }
```

My renderer script (app.js):

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const app = remote.app;

console.log(app.getPath('userData'))
```

According to console, userData is

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Electron

Shouldn't it be this?

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\my-electron-app

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. Let try with production app. Using electron-packager to package production app

Comment: @phuongle is it possible to create a directory in `app.getPath('userData')` during installation of the app (so that i dont have to include code to check if its already created and create it if not in my `main.js`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're pointing Electron to your script directly, meaning Electron is ignoring the existence of your `package.json` file entirely. Thus it does not know the name of your app.

Try:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron ."
}
```

Comment: That's the answer. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Not sure how this would work if package.json and your file are not in the same directory. It seems that electron expect your package.json to be in the same folder as your app, which is not always the case.

Comment: is it possible to create a directory in `app.getPath('userData')` during installation of the app (so that i dont have to include code to check if its already created and create it if not in my `main.js`?

Answer (score 0):

To complete the accepted answer, the `electron` command accepts either a folder or a file as a parameter.

According to `electron --help`, if you provide a folder, it should either contains an `index.js` file (your app) or a `package.json` file with an entry point. Thus you can specify any entry point you want:

```
{
    name:"my-electron-app",
    main: "app/index.js"
    ...
```

Short answer, set the `main` field of your package.json correctly and run `electron folder-containing-your-package-json`.